# Avoid non-composited animations - high CLS due to menu items (ocean-wp theme)

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed, cls

I'm struggling against a very high CLS on the home page of my website based on ocean-wp theme because all the elements in the menu (main and footer) are highlighted with the tag "CCS property not supported: color" (see sample in the attached screenshot).
Can you help me to understand where I'm wrong?
Thanks,
Domenico

I tried to change the color of the menu from "customize" but nothing happened.